# how to send the some value from first class to second class in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have an android app with 2 activity.
i tried to send value of three variables to another activity but it doesnt work here is my code:

CLASS 1

```
public long postCount;
    public long followerCount;
    public long followingCount;

    private async void LoginToAcc()
    {
        user.UserName = txtUser.Text;
        user.Password = txtPwd.Text;
        api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
            .SetUser(user)
            .Build();

        var loginReq = await api.LoginAsync();
        if (loginReq.Succeeded)
        {
            GetUserInfo();
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page2);
        }
    }
    private async void GetUserInfo()
    {
        var info = await api.GetUserInfoByIdAsync(pkid);
        if (info.Succeeded)
        {
           followerCount= info.Value.FollowerCount;
            followingCount = info.Value.FollowingCount;
            postCount = info.Value.MediaCount;
```

how can i send the value of followeCount,postCount,followingCount to second class?
you can see second activity here:

CLASS 2

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        txtPost = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labelPosts);
        txtfollower = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labelFollowers);
        txtfollowing = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labelFollowings);
        txtPost.Text +="\n"+ page1.postCount.ToString();
        txtfollower.Text += "\n" + page1.followerCount.ToString();
        txtfollowing.Text += "\n" + page1.followingCount.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What you mean _"but it doesn't work"_?

Comment: What is _first_ what is _second_ class here?

Comment: @SᴇM in the second class when i call one of them to get there value it wont get anything please see second class codes.

Comment: I don't see any `class code` here.

Comment: @SᴇM please refresh page i edited the post

Comment: What are the names of your classes?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with **[Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events)** to get value from other class or Task method.

Create a `TodoItem` Class which contain you want to passed parameters:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public long postCount { set; get; }
    public long followerCount { set; get; }
    public long followingCount { set; get; }

}
```

Create a *PassValueInterface* (Interface) to add method:

```
public interface PassValueInterface
{
    Task<TodoItem> PassTodoValue();
}
```

In **ClassOne** , get the `TodoItem` from task like http request:

```
public class ClassOne : PassValueInterface
{
    public async Task<TodoItem> PassTodoValue()
    {

        TodoItem todoItem = new TodoItem();
        todoItem.followerCount = 0;
        todoItem.followingCount = 0;
        todoItem.postCount = 0;

        // Here can be http request code to set value

        return todoItem;
    }


}
```

Finally, in *Other Class* or *ContentPage* class can get the `TodoItem`

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //-------Get TodoItem here-------------
    ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne();
    Console.WriteLine("----"+ GetTasksAsync(classOne).Result.followerCount);
    Console.WriteLine("----"+ GetTasksAsync(classOne).Result.followingCount); 
    Console.WriteLine("----"+ GetTasksAsync(classOne).Result.postCount);  
}
// from this method in other class
public Task<TodoItem> GetTasksAsync(ClassOne classOne)
{
     return classOne.PassTodoValue();
}
```

If other problems, refer to [Consume a RESTful Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest) can be helpful.